# How to reference .jar from other project with ant?

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, shared-libraries, android-support-library

I have project A. A needs to refernce the android support library which I have in project B. I would think it should be as easy as adding a class path entry such as:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="../B/libs/android-support-v4.jar"/>
```

For some reason, this is not working. It works fine from within Eclipse, but not from ant. Any suggestions?

Note: Both A & B are Android library projects -- not sure if this is what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A needs to refernce the android support library which I have in project B

Unless A itself depends upon B, please put a copy of the Android Support package JAR in A's `libs/` directory. So long as A and B have the same JAR for the same name, when Android builds an app that uses A and B, it will only use one copy of the JAR.

Comment: Thanks, I know this will work, but it feels like a work around and I'd prefer a more elegant solution. I'll give it a couple more days to see if anybody comes up with something more elegant. Otherwise, I'll accept your answer. Cheers!

Comment: @KarimVarela: "I'd prefer a more elegant solution" -- what you want is **far** less "elegant". Do not introduce unnecessary dependencies between projects. If A and B are unrelated, *make them be unrelated*, rather than having A depend upon a JAR in B just because a copy of the file happens to be located there. Conversely, if A and B *are* related, then just add B as a library project to A's project, and you'll pick up the JAR that way.